# Purpose of making overridden virtual function non-virtual

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, overriding, virtual-functions

Consider the following classes in C++11:

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void foo() = 0;
}

class Sub1 : public Base
{
public:
  virtual void foo() override {};
}

class Sub2 : public Base
{
public:
  void foo() override {};
}
```

What are the consequences of making the overridden function non-virtual as in `Sub2`?

Comment: Overrides of virtual functions are implicitly virtual.

Comment: There is no purpose other than economy. The function remains virtual by inheritance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An override of a virtual function is always virtual regardless of whether it's declared as such. Thus, having or not having the `virtual` keyword in the declaration of `Sub2::foo()` has no effect whatsoever as far as the language is concerned, since the `override` keyword means that the function must override a member function of a base class. From §10.3 [class.virtual]/p2 of the standard, emphasis added:

> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in
>   a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from `Base`, a
>   member function `vf` with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5),
>   cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as `Base::vf`
>   is declared, then `Derived::vf` is also virtual (**whether or not it
>   is so declared**) and it *overrides* `Base::vf`. For convenience we say
>   that any virtual function overrides itself.

Answer (score 9):

Omitting the word `virtual` does not make the function non-virtual. It does reduce the verbosity, the amount of visual noise, or in short, the way that the source code text can make an impression of just being too long-winded without any specific part of it introducing anything really new that can capture the reader's attention so that it all appears more or less like a gray mass of text, which of course can lead to some important details being overlooked, which is to say, inadvertently ignored. The `override` keyword is preferable.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-alf Is a method foo on a class derived from Sub2 also virtual given the parent foo method of Sub2 is also virtual?

Comment: @Matt: if it has the same signature, yes.